# Wide a dataframe and insert missing columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

**EDIT:** more data was added with `dput()` format.

I have the following products dataframe, with the `column` having the pattern **promo, marca, descripción, cantidad, precio**. Sometimes the promo is missing.

I need the dataframe in a wider form (like with `pivot_wider`), but where doesn't find a column, insert a `NA` value.

```
 # A tibble: 18 x 2
   text                                              column     
   <chr>                                             <chr>      
 1 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990                          promo      
 2 Pampers                                           marca      
 3 Pañales Desechables Premium Care XXG 112 Unidades descripción
 4 112 Un                                            cantidad   
 5 $27.490                                           precio     
 6 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990                          promo      
 7 Pampers                                           marca      
 8 Pañales Desechables Premium Care XG 112 Unidades  descripción
 9 112 Un                                            cantidad   
10 $27.490                                           precio     
11 Babysec                                           marca      
12 Toalla Húmeda Premium X 140/6                     descripción
13 1 Un                                              cantidad   
14 $2.590                                            precio     
15 Emuwipes                                          marca      
16 Toallitas Húmedas Premium 85 Un c/u Bolsa         descripción
17 2 Un                                              cantidad   
18 $2.650                                            precio
```

This is the output from `df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(...)`. Is there a way to shrink this output?

```
# A tibble: 18 x 6
      id promo               marca    descripción                            cantidad precio
   <int> <chr>               <chr>    <chr>                                  <chr>    <chr> 
 1     1 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$~ NA       NA                                     NA       NA    
 2     2 NA                  Pampers  NA                                     NA       NA    
 3     3 NA                  NA       Pañales Desechables Premium Care XXG ~ NA       NA    
 4     4 NA                  NA       NA                                     112 Un   NA    
 5     5 NA                  NA       NA                                     NA       $27.4~
 6     6 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$~ NA       NA                                     NA       NA    
 7     7 NA                  Pampers  NA                                     NA       NA    
 8     8 NA                  NA       Pañales Desechables Premium Care XG 1~ NA       NA    
 9     9 NA                  NA       NA                                     112 Un   NA    
10    10 NA                  NA       NA                                     NA       $27.4~
11    11 NA                  Babysec  NA                                     NA       NA    
12    12 NA                  NA       Toalla Húmeda Premium X 140/6          NA       NA    
13    13 NA                  NA       NA                                     1 Un     NA    
14    14 NA                  NA       NA                                     NA       $2.590
15    15 NA                  Emuwipes NA                                     NA       NA    
16    16 NA                  NA       Toallitas Húmedas Premium 85 Un c/u B~ NA       NA    
17    17 NA                  NA       NA                                     2 Un     NA    
18    18 NA                  NA       NA                                     NA       $2.650
```

The data:

```
text = c("2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990", "Pampers", 
"Pañales Desechables Premium Care XXG 112 Unidades", "112 Un", 
"$27.490", "2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990", "Pampers", "Pañales Desechables Premium Care XG 112 Unidades", 
"112 Un", "$27.490", "Babysec", "Toalla Húmeda Premium X 140/6", 
"1 Un", "$2.590", "Emuwipes", "Toallitas Húmedas Premium 85 Un c/u Bolsa", 
"2 Un", "$2.650", "Parent's Choice", "Toallitas Húmedas Ultra Soft con Aceite de Emu 160 Un", 
"160 Un", "$2.550", "Emuwipes", "Toallitas Húmedas sin Alcohol (2 Bolsas de 80 Un c/u) Bolsa 2 Un", 
"$1.990", "3 X$45.990Ahorro:$13.980", "Babysec", "Pañal Super Premium XXG68", 
"1 Un", "$19.990", "Parent's Choice", "Toallitas Húmedas Ultra Soft con Aceite de Emu y sin Aroma (2 Un de 80 Un c/u)", 
"160 Un", "$2.550", "2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990", "Pampers", "Pañales Desechables Premium Care G 124 Unidades", 
"124 Un", "$27.490", "Huggies")

column = c("promo", "marca", 
"descripción", "cantidad", "precio", "promo", "marca", "descripción", 
"cantidad", "precio", "marca", "descripción", "cantidad", "precio", 
"marca", "descripción", "cantidad", "precio", "marca", "descripción", 
"cantidad", "precio", "marca", "descripción", "precio", "promo", 
"marca", "descripción", "cantidad", "precio", "marca", "descripción", 
"cantidad", "precio", "promo", "marca", "descripción", "cantidad", 
"precio", "marca")
```

Comment: BTW, it is helpful to include your data in a reproducible format, e.g. by including the output of `dput(df)`, so that we can run the code without doing a bunch of reformatting just to recreate your `df`.

Comment: In order to widen your dataframe, the function must know which rows belong together (the function doesn’t care about row order). In your operation, you’ve used the index as the (effective) grouping identifier, so every entry gets its own row (with NAs for all other entries). If you add a grouping column, and use that column as argument as id, that should solve your issue.

Comment: Thakn you @JonSpring, I wasn't aware of that. To the second comment, I didn't knew how to get the grouping column.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a `precio` for every item, we could use the code below, which count how many `precio` entries have occurred in the prior rows. `lag(column, default = "")` is used to avoid having "NA" for the first item, which would break the cumulative count.

```
df %>%
  mutate(row = cumsum(lag(column, default = "") == "precio")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = column, values_from = text)


# A tibble: 4 x 6
    row promo                    marca    descripción                                       cantidad precio 
  <int> <chr>                    <chr>    <chr>                                             <chr>    <chr>  
1     0 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990 Pampers  Pañales Desechables Premium Care XXG 112 Unidades 112 Un   $27.490
2     1 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990 Pampers  Pañales Desechables Premium Care XG 112 Unidades  112 Un   $27.490
3     2 NA                       Babysec  Toalla Húmeda Premium X 140/6                     1 Un     $2.590 
4     3 NA                       Emuwipes Toallitas Húmedas Premium 85 Un c/u Bolsa         2 Un     $2.650
```

EDIT: Alternate approach using `marca`, but where `promo` is assigned to the next grouping (since it is assumed to always precede `marca` whenever it appears). Same output for the sample data.

```
df %>%
  mutate(row = cumsum(column == "marca") + if_else(column == "promo", 1, 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = column, values_from = text)
```

Source data

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    text = c("2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990","Pampers",
                             "Pañales Desechables Premium Care XXG 112 Unidades","112 Un","$27.490",
                             "2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990","Pampers",
                             "Pañales Desechables Premium Care XG 112 Unidades","112 Un","$27.490",
                             "Babysec","Toalla Húmeda Premium X 140/6",
                             "1 Un","$2.590","Emuwipes",
                             "Toallitas Húmedas Premium 85 Un c/u Bolsa","2 Un","$2.650"),
                  column = c("promo","marca",
                             "descripción","cantidad","precio","promo",
                             "marca","descripción","cantidad","precio","marca",
                             "descripción","cantidad","precio","marca",
                             "descripción","cantidad","precio")
      )
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of, but didn't manage to code it. How would you patch this to work with `marca` instead of `precio`?

Comment: Added an alternative based on `marca`. Since `promo`, when it appears, appears prior to `marca`, I shift those to the next grouping.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** to concerns raised by OP and others with  new provided data and with the knowledge gained here: [Recognize a given pattern in a vector and add the lacking elements to get the repitition of the given pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68885775/recognize-a-given-pattern-in-a-vector-and-add-the-lacking-elements-to-get-the-re)

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(column) %>% 
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = column,
        values_from = text
    )
```

Gives:

```
     row promo                    marca           descripción                                                                    cantidad precio 
   <int> <chr>                    <chr>           <chr>                                                                          <chr>    <chr>  
 1     1 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990 Pampers         Pañales Desechables Premium Care XXG 112 Unidades                              112 Un   $27.490
 2     2 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990 Pampers         Pañales Desechables Premium Care XG 112 Unidades                               112 Un   $27.490
 3     3 3 X$45.990Ahorro:$13.980 Babysec         Toalla Húmeda Premium X 140/6                                                  1 Un     $2.590 
 4     4 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990 Emuwipes        Toallitas Húmedas Premium 85 Un c/u Bolsa                                      2 Un     $2.650 
 5     5 NA                       Parent's Choice Toallitas Húmedas Ultra Soft con Aceite de Emu 160 Un                          160 Un   $2.550 
 6     6 NA                       Emuwipes        Toallitas Húmedas sin Alcohol (2 Bolsas de 80 Un c/u) Bolsa 2 Un               1 Un     $1.990 
 7     7 NA                       Babysec         Pañal Super Premium XXG68                                                      160 Un   $19.990
 8     8 NA                       Parent's Choice Toallitas Húmedas Ultra Soft con Aceite de Emu y sin Aroma (2 Un de 80 Un c/u) 124 Un   $2.550 
 9     9 NA                       Pampers         Pañales Desechables Premium Care G 124 Unidades                                NA       $27.490
10    10 NA                       Huggies         NA                                                                             NA       NA
```

**First answer:**

We could create  a unique identifier row for each `column` and then use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    group_by(column) %>% 
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = column,
        values_from = text
    )
```

```
    row promo                    marca    descripción                                       cantidad precio 
  <int> <chr>                    <chr>    <chr>                                             <chr>    <chr>  
1     1 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990 Pampers  Pañales Desechables Premium Care XXG 112 Unidades 112 Un   $27.490
2     2 2 X$39.990Ahorro:$14.990 Pampers  Pañales Desechables Premium Care XG 112 Unidades  112 Un   $27.490
3     3 NA                       Babysec  Toalla Húmeda Premium X 140/6                     1 Un     $2.590 
4     4 NA                       Emuwipes Toallitas Húmedas Premium 85 Un c/u Bolsa         2 Un     $2.650
```

Comment: Dont you worry about that anyway. I still voted the answer since OP did specify that PROMO is the one missing. The other answers will also fail if one precio was to be taken away. So your answer is valid. This answer is the robust one out of the provided answers

Comment: This works, but gives a wrong output because groups all the `promo` values in the upper side of the dataframe.

Comment: you mean the order of promo?

Comment: When the code doesn't finds a promo, moves the subsequent values up. The error shows up with the new data I have uploaded.

Comment: I think it's a liability that this approach is more "robust" -- it will provide output even if that output is wrong, whereas the others will fail when the underlying assumptions that make up a grouping are failing.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dcast` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), create a formula with cumulative sum (based on taking the `lag` of 'column' (`shift`), check if the values are equal to 'precio', get the cumulative sum (`cumsum`)) with the 'column', and specify the `value.var` as 'text' in `dcast` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(df), cumsum(shift(column, fill = "") == "precio" )~ column, value.var = 'text')
```

Comment: Nice trick with the `cumsum` and `shift` combination. I can see what it does, but it would be helpful to add a few words on what exactly happens and why it works in this case.