# Recognize a given pattern in a vector and add the lacking elements to get the repitition of the given pattern

Tags: r, pattern-matching, sequence

This question is related to this [Wide a dataframe and insert missing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68883838/wide-a-dataframe-and-insert-missing-columns/68884156#68884156)

Suppose we have a **given** pattern of 5 elements in this order: `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"`

This pattern is repeated say 10 times. But sometimes some elements are lacking (see picture my vector (orange).

**Is it possible in `R` to recognize the repeated pattern and fill in the lacking elements (see picture my desired output).**

My vector:

```
my.vector <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "B", "C", 
               "D", "E", "B", "C", "D", "E", "B", "C", "D", "E", "B", "C", "D", 
               "E", "B", "C", "D", "E", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
               "E", "B")

my.vector
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "B" "C" "D" "E" "B" "C" "D" "E" "B" "C" "D" "E" "B" "C" "D" "E" "B" "C" "D" "E" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "B"
```

A graphical explanation:

**Given pattern:**
[image]

**My vector:**
[image]

**My desired output: Red marked elements to be added**
[image]

Comment: pattern is provided!

Comment: What is the threshold for match? Should every A be paired with "B C D E" following, should every E have "A B C D" appended before it if not already there? Or do we need 3 or 4 of the 5 to call it an instance of the pattern?

Comment: Such "patterns" are what are known as "motifs" in bioinfomatics. And sometimes they do appear as sequence repeats There are lots of support for managing such occurences in the BioConductor packages.

Comment: @Jon Spring it should always be A B C D E.

Comment: Do elements ever repeat within a pattern? For example, a pattern such as A B A D D A D B C D E?

Comment: No. Always  A B C D E,  A B C D E,  A B C D E,  A B C D E,  A B C D E etc...

Comment: I am implementing give me a few seconds please!!! :-)

Comment: it may not work if you have patterns like `A A A A B C`

Comment: That was my concern, too, @akrun. TarJae says that elements do not repeat within the pattern, so it should be fine?

Comment: My second solution may still work i.e. with `rowid`.  I haven't tested it though

Comment: Works perfect.!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a grouping column based on the `diff` of `match`ing index with `LETTERS[1:5]`, `split` (or use any grouping functions like `tapply` etc), and create a `union` with the 'LETTERS[1:5]`,` unlist`the`list`and`unname`

```
unname( unlist(lapply(split(my.vector, cumsum(c(TRUE, 
     diff(match(my.vector, LETTERS[1:5])) != 1))),
       function(x) union(LETTERS[1:5], x))))
```

-output

```
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A"
[37] "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

---

Or another option is `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
tibble(col1 = my.vector) %>%
    group_by(rn = rowid(col1)) %>%
    complete(col1 = LETTERS[1:5]) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pull(col1)
```

-output

```
1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A"
[37] "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```